# Why the view content is not centered?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my result

[image]

Although I am explicitly stating that the arc center is the center of the view.

This is my code:

```
let count = colors.count-1
        var index: Int = initialIndex
        for oneArray in points {
            let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[0]))
            let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[1]))
            let radius: CGFloat = self.frame.height/4
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
                endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
                clockwise: true)
            let color = UIColor(red: colors[count-index][0], green: colors[count-index][1], blue: colors[count-index][2], alpha: 1.0)
            path.lineWidth = CGFloat(4)
            if ++index >= count {
                index = 0
            }
            color.setStroke()
            path.stroke()
        }
```

And the view (that's the circle inside) has the correct constrains for height and width. As you see here

[image]

This is the constrain of the view `Wainting Circle View`
as you see, i am setting the hight and the width relative to the supper view,
thus the center of that view should be correct, as a result, the self.center that i am using should draw at the center

[image]

Comment: have you set to constraints with a specific width and height? or with spacing to nearest neighbour?

Comment: Where do you set `center`?

Comment: Is `center` a local variable or is it `self.center`? `self.center` is the center relative to the superview not the center of the bounds.  You'd want `CGPoint(x:bounds.midX, y:bounds.midY)`

Comment: @thelaws it is supposed to be the center of the view, and it is writtin in the arc in the path ui bezier.

Comment: @BrianNickel and that is what i want, the center of the supper view, that is why i used center, which is the center of the supper view

Comment: guys i update my quesiton, you look for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining the center of your arch a `self.center` which the docs describe as:

> The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview and is measured in points. Setting this property changes the values of the frame properties accordingly.

This is essentially the same as `CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)`, meaning that if your view isn't flush with the top of the superview superview, `center.x` is going to be different from the center of the view.

For example, if your view has `frame == CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:100, height:100)`, it will have `center == CGPoint(x: 50 + 100/2, y: 50 + 100 /2) == CGPoint(x:100, y:100)` which is the bottom right corner of the view.

If you want the circle to be centered in the center of the view, you should pick your center based of the bounds, which is in a view-relative coordinate system:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
    radius: radius,
    startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
    endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
    clockwise: true)
```

Comment: your code solve the problem, but i still don't understand why? could you please descripe in simple enlgish ? (if you speak italian, i understand more)